# How to get my sidebar to move to the side CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am new to CSS? HTML and am trying to get my sidebar to move to the side but it is not working. I have my html site set up into three div areas. One 'sidebar' area, one 'main content' area and a 'content' are where both the sidebar and main content are to be shown.

This is my CSS code...

```
#content{ 
padding:10px; 
background-color: #eee; 
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
width: 900px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
margin-top: 150px;
}


#mainContent{
float: left;
display: block; 
width: 230 px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0 15px; 
background:#9c9;
}

#sidebar{
float: right;
display: block;  
margin: 0; 
padding: 0 10px;
width: 250px; 
border-left: 2px solid black;
}
```

this does not give me what I want. The age looks like this: [image: PracticePage]

I want the sidebar (which is currently under) to appear on the side of the green area.

Comment: You have a space in your CSS in `#mainContent`: `width: 230 px;` Remove this space!

Comment: Is the sidebar inside the content or what?

Comment: Post your HTML markups as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the `#mainContent` class. Remove it:

```
#mainContent{
float: left;
display: block; 
width: 230px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0 15px; 
background:#9c9;
}
```

CSS doesn't like spaces between the numerical value and the unit.